# How to match zero or one times in `Dir.glob` pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to open files like "ab23" or "dca-5333" by `Dir.glob`.

In Regex I can write a pattern like `/^\w+-?\d+$/`, but pattern in `Dir.glob` is different.
Especially I couldn't find equivalent expression for the function `?`: `match zero or one times`.

How can I write the pattern in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many patterns for Dir.glob here: http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir2.htm. I don't think you can get this exact regular expression translated with Dir.glob (to match something 0 or more times, you use * just like in regular expressions, but your query is quite specific). Maybe something like this would be better:

```
Dir.glob('*').select { |element| element[/^\w+-?\d+$/] }
```